# Xdebug not stopping on breakpoints set in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug one of my unit tests in PhpStorm.

I set a breakpoint in the test code and it was ignored. When I put `xdebug_break` it works.

I am using PhpStorm 2017.1.4

Here is the output from phpunit (with identifying directory names replaced with question marks)

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /mnt/dev/michael/mylibrary/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /mnt/dev/michael/mylibrary/tests/bootstrap.php --configuration /mnt/dev/???/mylibrary/phpunit.xml FilterDefinitionTest /mnt/dev/???/mylibrary/tests/unit/admin/includes/helpers/DbHelpers/QueryBuilder/FilterDefinitions/FilterDefinitionTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 1:37 PM ...
PHPUnit 5.4.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2 with Xdebug 2.5.1
Configuration: /mnt/dev/???/mylibrary/phpunit.xml
```

Comment: *"I set a breakpoint in the test code and it was ignored. When I put xdebug_break it works."* 1) What kind of line is that (want to see it)? 2) What xdebug log says about both debug sessions (any difference)?